# Java Population Growth Loop and Method; Improper Output

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, population

My task is to create a program that models population growth using the formula `x_new = r * x_previous * (1-x_previous)`, where `r` is the fecundity parameter and `x` is the population. I have a working program and method. However, my math isn't checking out. I should be able to test for an initial population of `.01`, a fecundity parameter of `1.1`, `1000` time steps and get an answer around `.09`).

Here's my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6Question3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("The population, p: ");
    double p = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The fecundity rate, r: ");
    double r = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Number of Time Steps, n: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int i; //iterations

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Simulation with starting population " + p); 
    System.out.println("Running " + n + " steps");
    System.out.println("Varying fecundicity 1, 1.1, ..., 4.9, 5");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

    System.out.println("r = " + r + " final population = " + p);

    r = r + 0.1;

    p = populationGrowth(p, r);

    }

}

public static double populationGrowth(double population, double fecundicity) 
{
    double p;

    return (fecundicity * population * (1 - population));

}
}
```

And my output is correctly formatted with the iterations, but the population results is wrong:

```
Simulation with starting population 0.01
Running 10000 steps
Varying fecundicity 1, 1.1, ..., 4.9, 5
r = 1.0 final population = 0.01
r = 1.1 final population = 0.01089
r = 1.2000000000000002 final population = 0.012925689480000004
r = 1.3000000000000003 final population = 0.01658620084090661

.
.
.
```

Any ideas what could be the cause of the pain? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When `r` reach `5.2` about iteration `43` your growth function goes to negative numbers, because `x_previous is > 1` ... so `1-x_previous < 0`, are you sure that model is right...it seems a conceptual problem. try to model it in an excel.

Another thing, you increment you `r` before calculate next `p` value. Are you sure is that right?